# Proper Nikon D5600 Cables for Micro to Micro for IOS and Android Phone and/or tablet.

Tags: cables, nikon-d5600

Having totally [given up](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/87466/how-do-i-connect-a-phone-to-a-nikon-d5600-using-bluetooth-or-wi-fi) on using my "built in WiFi" with my D5600 I have decided to go with cable. So I picked up the USB to micro cable specifically designed to work with the D5600. Works just fine with what I need, which is to use DSLRDashboard for time-lapse. All that is fine but the lap top is really not my first choice to use for this.

I also have an IPad mini which would be my first choice, a Samsung S-7 which would be a close second choice. The problem is I can't find cabling to go between these devices and the D5600.

Are these cables even made, and where can I find them if so?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you hoping to control the camera via the iPad or S7? Or are you just looking to use the cable connection for file transfer?

Comment: Control the camera

Answer (score 2):

There are two different things you will need, the first is a USB OTG adapter. In its normal mode, the phone is designed to act as an 'accessory' to a lot of devices (e.g. memory card for the PC), a USB OTG adapter (may have even come with the phone) creates a USB female port, and tells the devices connecting to the phone that the phone is acting as a 'master'.

Check with your device, as some do not allow host mode USB. My understanding with qDLSRDashboard (I use this on android) is that it does not work via USB to DSLR camera's due to limitations on the camera connection kit.

It does work on Samsung Galaxy devices, but it is much easier to use on a bigger screen (e.g. if i use it on my samsung galaxy S7, the screen is very cramped, whereas my Galaxy Tab S2 is much easier to use it on)

There are other ways to use it via the mini, you might have to have a look but my understanding is you can use a very specific brand of portable travel router to kind of 'bridge' the devices via WIFI, and the camera via USB to the router.

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that Nikon D5600 has a mini usb and the Galaxy S7 also has a mini usb, you need a mini usb to mini usb cable.

There are several apps on the Play Store that enable commanding your DSLR from the phone, I have not tested any but some state that they support D5600.

Comment: Have you ever used mini to mini cable with a D5600 and successfully used any app? The D5600 does not use a regular USB to mini, I am thinking it would not function with a regular mini to mini. Do you know from experience?

Comment: No, I haven't used this myself, but such a cable is not expensive and you can give it a try