# Nikon D5600 : Android mobile cannot connect to camera's wifi (Snapbridge App Problem)

Tags: nikon, android, wifi, nikon-d5600, snapbridge

I am able to connect my mobile (Samsung S6 Edge) to the camera (Nikon D5600) via **Bluetooth** in the **Snapbridge** app.

**PROBLEM:** When I press the "Remote Photography" or "Download Photos" button, the Snapbridge app successfully starts the camera's wifi but keep trying to connect it for an indefinite time. I have already disconnected my home WiFi (basically my mobile is not connected to any Wifi). If I go the Wifi setting of my mobile, I can see that my Mobile is connected to the Camera's wifi but the Snapbridge app does not recognize that connection and hence I am not able to use "Remote Photography".

> The Snapbridge app keeps trying to connect to the Camera's wifi as
>   shown in the screenshot (but if I check my mobile's wifi setting, I
>   see that the mobile is already connected to the Camera's WiFi).

[image: Snapbridge App Problem]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I connect a phone to a Nikon D5600 using Bluetooth or Wi-Fi?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/87466/how-do-i-connect-a-phone-to-a-nikon-d5600-using-bluetooth-or-wi-fi)

Comment: This seems to be more about the snapbridge app than the wi-fi connection, which the phone is saying is good.